# Unpivot tables script error

Tags: oracle, unpivot

I have a table called rp_resolution_master.

```
CREATE TABLE "REQUEST_PORTAL"."RP_RESOLUTION_MASTER" 
   ( "RM_ID" NUMBER, 
    "SR_ID" NUMBER, 
    "REQUEST_STATUS" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "UPDATED_ON" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
    "INTERNAL_COMMUNICATION" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N'
   );
```

I am running an unpivot query on this.

```
 SELECT *
   From Rp_Resolution_Master
Unpivot INCLUDE NULLS ( 
          value For measures In ( rm_id, request_status, Comments
                                , updated_by, internal_communication)
                      ) 
 where sr_id = 1004707 
   And Updated_On = ( Select Max(Updated_On) 
                        From Rp_Resolution_Master 
                       Where Sr_Id = 1004707);
```

But I get an error

> ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding
>   expression
>   01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 3 Column: 51

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are attempting to `UNPIVOT` columns that are not the same datatype. All of the values being unpivoted must be the same, similar to when you use a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` query, each value in the columns must be of the same datatype.

Since the `RM_ID` column is a `number` and the others are `varchar2` then you need to you will need to use a subquery which to perform a `cast()` of the `RM_ID` column:

```
select *
from 
(
  SELECT cast(rm_id as varchar2(200)) rm_id,
    request_status,
    Comments,
    updated_by,
    internal_communication,
    Updated_On,
    sr_id
  From Rp_Resolution_Master
)
Unpivot INCLUDE NULLS ( 
          value For measures In ( rm_id, request_status, Comments
                                , updated_by, internal_communication)
                      ) 
where sr_id = 1004707 
  And Updated_On = ( Select Max(Updated_On) 
                     From Rp_Resolution_Master 
                     Where Sr_Id = 1004707);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/493a4/4) of the syntax working